# Cannot read property 'getPositionForOffset$1' of null

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

There is a bug in my flutter web app which shown up **very rarely** after changing the app localization at runtime, this dynamic behavior implemented using `provider` and `flutter_localizations` packages as the official docs described [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) and changes the `locale` and `darkTheme > fontFamily` property of `MaterialApp`.


This is the stack-trace using `flutter build web --profile --dart-define=Dart2jsOptimization=O0`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPositionForOffset$1' of null
    at RenderParagraph.hitTestChildren$2$position (main.dart.js:96010)
    at RenderParagraph.hitTest$2$position (main.dart.js:90914)
    at RenderShiftedBox_hitTestChildren_closure.call$2 (main.dart.js:98256)
    at BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset$3$hitTest$offset$position (main.dart.js:90784)
    at _RenderAppBarTitleBox.hitTestChildren$2$position (main.dart.js:98249)
    at _RenderAppBarTitleBox.hitTest$2$position (main.dart.js:90914)
    at RenderSemanticsAnnotations.hitTestChildren$2$position (main.dart.js:96532)
    at RenderSemanticsAnnotations.hitTest$2$position (main.dart.js:90914)
    at RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin_defaultHitTestChildren_closure.call$2 (main.dart.js:91033)
    at BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset$3$hitTest$offset$position (main.dart.js:90784)
```

OR

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPositionForOffset$1' of null
    at RenderParagraph.hitTestChildren$2$position (main.dart.js:96020)
    at RenderParagraph.hitTest$2$position (main.dart.js:90924)
    at RenderShiftedBox_hitTestChildren_closure.call$2 (main.dart.js:98266)
    at BoxHitTestResult.addWithPaintOffset$3$hitTest$offset$position (main.dart.js:90794)
    at RenderPositionedBox.hitTestChildren$2$position (main.dart.js:98259)
    at RenderPositionedBox.hitTest$2$position (main.dart.js:90924)
    at RenderConstrainedBox.hitTestChildren$2$position (main.dart.js:96542)
    at RenderConstrainedBox.hitTest$2$position (main.dart.js:90924)
    at RenderExcludeSemantics.hitTestChildren$2$position (main.dart.js:96542)
    at RenderExcludeSemantics.hitTest$2$position
```

*Any help would be greatly appreciated*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to provide a `UniqueKey()` to `MaterialApp()` when the top most widget tree is going to rebuild after a localization change requested, because the previous calculated states or constraints are not necessarily compatible with the new `fontFamily` or `locale`. Also note that there might be another more efficient solution to this problem but this will do the job.